# Hangout chat api (chat.spaces().messages().create) throws Permission error (403)

Tags: google-hangouts

I have created a service account in Google Api console to use Hangout apis. The api calls are authorized with the service account credentials. But when I call

```
chat.spaces().messages().create(parent='spaces/myroomid', body={'text': 'Test message'}).execute()
```

googleapiclient throws the following error:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/myroomid/messages?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">

In the above code I am using the actual chat room id in place of myroomid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I did not associate the bot to the room. Working now.